# How can I cut cement sewer line to add cleanout?

Tags: repair, sewer

I have a home built in 1950 with a cement sewer line. I have had to have
the line cleared twice in the last two years. The last time they sent a 
camera down the line and the line seems root free with no obvious broken
sections. The  line had a few slightly bumpy sections but I suspect not
too bad considering the age. I would like to install a cleanout so I don't
have to pull the toilet next time it backs up. I dug the hole
and found the pipe to be what I think is 5" cement type. I need
to know if there are rubber sleeves for this size of pipe so I can add
the "Y" ABS fittings also what is the best way to cut the cement so as to
get a clean edge?

Answer (score 4):

Concrete chainsaws can be rented.  They would do all the cutting from above and simplify the excavation.  Industrial sized hydraulic ones cut open doorways in poured concrete walls.

[image: Concrete chainsaw]

Another option would be a flexible saddle tap..,which installs by drilling the concrete line with the proper coring bit.  [Fernco](https://www.fernco.com/plumbing/flexible-couplings/flexible-tap-saddles) makes a wide line of drain fittings

[image]

Comment: The saddle tap would definitely be easier to install, too.